# Is drawing an animation more efficient than animating an image array?

Tags: ios, animation, user-interface

For basic animations like transitions and intro loaders, what is more efficient? Drawing with CG or animating an array of images?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how big the images are, but usually that’s the better option. Core Graphics isn’t really meant for real-time drawing. Core Animation can handle a lot, depending on the complexity of your animation; it kind of depends on what you’re trying to do.